# Where to get complete manpages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, manpage, debian-based

In Debian 7 and in Linux Mint 16 I don't get any parameters/options when typing

```
man insmod
```

or

```
insmod --help
```

But I know there are parameters, e.g insmod --probe

Where can I get complete manpages for my system or which distribution provides complete manpages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`insmod` was before provided by the `module-init-tools` project which has been replaced by the `kmod` project. The "new" insmod from kmod does not provide this options anymore.

Found a hint on [`Arch` news](https://www.archlinux.org/news/kmod-replaces-module-init-tools/) about the change. This will apply for Debian too:

> With module-init-tools being declared a dead project by its current maintainer, a new project has stepped up to take its place: kmod. This is intended to be a drop-in replacement, though deprecated functionality in module-init-tools has not been reimplemented.

The options `-p`, `-s` and `-f` are outdated and now ignored. Long option names for that params aren't valid anymore.

You can check the [source code](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/kernel/kmod/kmod.git/tree/tools/insmod.c?id=ae58de0fcb4a6528dd365e23d383bbe2eaf2d566#n71)

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for the link to the sourcecode.